# how to mock DynamoDB mapper transactionwrite() method using Mockito?

Tags: mockito, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My use-case is that I am using dynamoDB mapper's transactionWrite() method. I am doing 2 put operations in my TransactionWriteRequest.

Now, when I am trying to verify the same using  `verify(dynamoDBmapper).transactionWrite(writeRequest);`

**Output**

```
 => Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
     [java] dynamoDBMapper.transactionWrite(
     [java]     ...dynamodbv2.datamodeling.TransactionWriteRequest@4ee37ca3
     [java] );
     [java] -> at
    ...MyTestClass.myMethod_withValidData_returnSuccess(MyTestClass.java:99)
     [java] Actual invocation has different arguments:
     [java] dynamoDBMapper.transactionWrite(
     [java]     ...dynamodbv2.datamodeling.TransactionWriteRequest@45c8d09f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using [Unitils ReflectionAssert](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html) which compares objects recursively using reflection.